# Web cam streaming in web application to java server

Tags: java, streaming, webcam, rtp, rtmp

I'm implementing a face based network authentication system and I'm looking for a good solution of how to  stream video over the network. I'd like to get audio&video from user's webcam, display webcam output in user's browser and stream media through (RTP/RTMP/web sockets ?) to my JAVA server (or extra - something supported by Tomcat. That would make things a lot easier).

After several hours of googling I'm really confused and have no idea what would be the cleanest and most effort minimizing solution, additionally supported by multiple browsers. I have no restrictions on which technology to use on client side.

I'm really open to all proposals and looking for opinions on that subject for any of you who has any experience in that subject.

Comment: Do you want to get videos from the webcams, or just get a screenshot from a video and upload it to your web server? If the latter, you can check out this demo: http://www.dynamsoft.com/Demo/Webcam/online_demo_Webcam.aspx